# Image path in CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-4, background-image, less

I'm using some CSS framework and trying to show icon (using class selector with *background-image* property). Lets say, my file structure is:

```
Content / site.css
Content / Folder1  / framework.css
Content / Folder1  / Folder2       / framework-images.css
Content / Folder1  / Folder2       / framework-icon1.png
```

**site.css** looks like:

```
@include "Folder1/framework.css";
...
```

**framework.css** like:

```
@include "Folder2/framework-images.css";
...
```

**framework-images.css** is:

```
.selector {
    background-image: url("icon1.png");
}
```

But when I'm trying to add to my html-element class "selector" Firefox dev tools shows me that it trying to load icon from here:

```
http://localhost:1234/Content/~/Content/Folder1/Folder2/icon.png
```

while correct path is (**am I right?**):

```
~/Content/Folder1/Folder2/icon.png
```

or just

```
http://localhost:1234/Content/Folder1/Folder2/icon.png
```

So where can be mistake? How to tell client to use correct path?

P.S. If it matters I'm using dotless (Less css). Other words, all **.css** is actually **.less**.

P.P.S. This is ASP.NET MVC4 app.

**Update:**
As @djfarrelly pointed out, the problem was in incorrect path in *background-image: url(...)*. I've changed it to:

```
background-image: url("/Content/Folder1/Folder2/Icon1.png");
```

and it started working.
But I'm still confused. Can anyone explain why it doesn't working without full path specifying?

Comment: Do you mind posting the line where you assign the class, it is unclear how the "~" character got in there (The css could be correct and the problem rely somewhere else).

Comment: @Ulises I'm pretty certain this is part of LESS magic:  it generates the URL for you, including the tilde.  Is the generated url actually pointing to the wrong location or are you just bothered by its appearance?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I was not familiar with LESS

Comment: I suppose that the reason is not in LESS, because as far as I know **~/Content/** is MVC4 stuff. I'm pretty sure that it is similar to **../../Content/** for ASP.NET MVC3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your references to images should be in reference to the root folder in your website to avoid confusion.  Have you tried to change your css to reference from the root:

```
.selector {
    background-image: url("/Content/Folder1/Folder2/icon1.png");
}
```

If you include the `/` that should clean it up.

**EDIT:**
I originally posted this w/ `../` instead of the correct `/` to reference the root folder.

Comment: I thought that background-image url should be related to css file. I've tried to specify path as you mentioned, but dev.tools indicated **http://localhost:4883/Content/~/Content/Folder1/Folder2/icon1.png**. After that I've tried url("/Content/...") without ".." at start - and it works. Thanks for pointing on problem's origin.

Comment: Yeah, I've also thought about that, but I haven't found any proof. Have you?